# Missing man page of ghc

Tags: haskell, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, ghc

I installed the latest stable version of GHC following instructions from  [here](https://www.haskell.org/downloads/linux) on my `Ubuntu 14.04` `64-bit` machine. However, after installation finished, I find that man pages of command `ghc`, `ghci`, `runhaskell` etc are missing. It displays

```
ajay@ajay:~$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.8.4
ajay@ajay:~$ man ghc
No manual entry for ghc
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
```

Also, the commands

```
cabal update
cabal install alex happy
```

require `sudo` permission and when I prefix `sudo`, it says

```
sudo: cabal: command not found
```

I could access `man` pages when I'd installed `ghc` from Ubuntu `apt-get` repository. How do I install man pages now as I need them for reference.

Comment: I don’t think that the bindist ships the manpages, or at least not in a common place. Such integration effort is the value added by your distribution when you take their packages.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner I am wondering what reason could be there to not ship the man pages. It's a huge turnoff against using the latest stable version. Anyway, how can I check if the distribution comes with a man page, just in case?

Comment: Manpages are usually named `ghc.1` or `ghc.1.gz`. Check if the tarball contains such a file somewhere.

Comment: The URL with the GHC installation instructions no longer works. I get a 404 response.